# How to compile/combine multiple lines of code inside a function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, function, return

I have few lines of code wherein I am reading a csv file (df), manipulating some rows, columns of it, appending it with another csv file (esg)

```
df = df.append(esg)
df['SourceUrl'] = df['SourceUrl'].apply(lambda x: x.lstrip('htps://')if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan)
df['AvailableAt'] = df['AvailableAt'].apply(lambda x: processDate(x))
df['PublishedAt'] = df['PublishedAt'].apply(lambda x: processDate(x))
df['LastModified'] = df['LastModified'].apply(lambda x: processDate(x))
df["sig_compid_pubdt"] = df["CompanyId"]+"_"+df["PublishedAt"]
```

Now, I want to know that

1. How can I compile all these above lines of code within a function ??
2. What are the arguments which is needed to be passed and how will I know it??
3. What is to be returned?? How is 'return' keyword used?? In what conditions, is it necessary to be used??

Suggestions please

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df.head().to_string())` just after `df = df.append(esg)` or the first five lines of your csv file

Comment: Presumably, you would take `df` and `esg` as parameters, and return the combined `df`.  Something like `def combine(df, esg):`